# Get row index of all non-empty cells in a column in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to create a function that gives me a list of all the nonempty row indices in the example shown below (i.e., 3,4,6,7,8,9,12,15).

After that, I want to select, for example, the third number in this list (i.e., 6).

I can't figure out how to make it happen (I am still fairly new to Google Sheet formulas), so very thankful for your help!

Sheet example:

[image: example of sheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It is not quite clear to me what you need.*

**I think** you are asking for ***the # of the 1st row below 3rd empty row***

```
=SMALL(ArrayFormula(IF(B1:B="",,ROW(B1:B))),3)
```

[image]

You can also find **the # of empty rows** using:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B1:B<>"",,ROW(B1:B)))
```

Change it to the following to get **a list of non-empty rows**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B1:B="",,ROW(B1:B)))
```

In any case, I have also included a couple more useful formulas

**the # of the 3rd empty row**

```
=SMALL(ArrayFormula(IF(B1:B<>"",,ROW(B1:B))),3)
```

and finally, **the row content of the above formula**

```
=INDEX(B1:B,SMALL(ArrayFormula(IF(B1:B="",,ROW(B1:B))),3),1)
```

*(if still facing issues, do let us know)*